# What determines Zoom Extent in MapBox Studio

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

When uploading data to Mapbox Studio, a zoom extent is attributed to the dataset/tileset after processing. What controls this attribute?

I've uploaded datasets that I want to use at Zoom Extent different than those that are assigned and I don't see any way to edit this.

I've seen this behaviour when adding GeoJSON or shp

Comment: Looks like a work around is to upload files via Studio Classic where you can specify zoom levels. Does not really answer the question though and takes a long time